# app:layout_marginBottom is not working well with android constraint layout

Tags: android, margin, android-constraintlayout

Is there any reason why the following layout_marginBottom is not working?
However, if I use layout_marginTop on the second view it does work well

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ade4ad">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I add exactly the same problem, and I fixed it by adding to your first textView the following constraint : app:layout_constraintBottomToBottomOf="@+id/second". Then the marginBottom worked well

Comment: You need to have a constraint to have a margin. For eg., for bottom margin bottom constraint is must. Similar for other sides also.

Answer (score 64):

In order to

```
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
```

work well, you should use

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: You have to apply constraints to the top and bottom of all views if you want top and bottom margins to be respected.  The same goes with left and right constraints and left and right margins.

Answer (score 27):

Layout top/bottom margin works only when:

1. constraints in the same direction need to connect with their next neighbor child, like a unidirectional linked list.
2. last constraint in the direction must be set.

In your case, you need to set "layout_constraintBottom_toXXXXX" for each view in the chain, and last view set bottom to parent.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ade4ad">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/second"
        android:background="#000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/third"
        android:background="#fff"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Moreover, reverse dependency is not required except you want "layout_marginTop" works.

Comment: Got it. Simple said: A view's constraints only respect the margins that the view defines itself.

Answer (score 11):

you can use that trick, create a space bellow, align to parent bottom

```
<Space
   android:id="@+id/space"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

and align your view on top of the space
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/space"
like so

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/howNext"
    style="@style/white_action_btn_no_border"
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/got_it_next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/space"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, its `ConstraintLayout` so you have to give `Left`, `Right`, `Bottom`, `Top` `Constraint` to Relevant Layout, in your case You have to give `TextView` first `Bottom_Top` Constraint to `TextView` second. so you can get Margin between Two `TextView`.

Your layout should be like below.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ade4ad">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first" 
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/first" 
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/first" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't explain why android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" on the first view is not working (also with your code).