# Why marginBottom isn't working in Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, margins

Could someome explain me why `android:layout_marginBottom` doesn't work in a Spinner?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It doesn't matter if I use `android:layout_marginBottom` or `android:layout_margin`. However, If I use `android:layout_margin` it adds top, right and left margin. Why the only margin that does't work is the bottom?

[image: Example]

Thanks.

Comment: this is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931337/applayout-marginbottom-is-not-working-well-with-android-constraint-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about `Spinner` specifically - if you use two `TextView`s the behavior stays the same.

Some observations on "why" and "how":

- the `Spinner` top and start is constrained to the top and start of the parent `ViewGroup`. Since you don't specify a bottom (or end) constraint, a bottom margin is meaningless
- the TextView on the other hand has a top constraint - if you let it have a top margin, this will have the desired effect.

Now you could say "well, then I'll just add the bottom constraint to the `Spinner`". Unfortunately this is not enough (and here I really don't know *why* the `ConstraintLayout` solver decides to ignore the margin...)

If you want to set a margin to the `Spinner`, then the two `View`s have to belong to a complete vertical chain:

*parent top <- Spinner <-> TextView -> parent bottom*

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: screenshot of ui editor]

Answer (score 1):

connect constrain from the button to view or parent then it will affect
`$` app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="" `

Answer (score 1):

You need to constraint the spinner to bottom:

**1st method:**
`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

**2nd method:**
constraint the spinner to bottom by drag it until the bottom of your root view